# JavaScript canvas make transparent image darker

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have an image I am drawing with ctx.drawImage, and it has transparency. I want to darken the image so I am using a fillRect with rgba(0,0,0,0.5) but this darkens the transparent parts of the image too. So I am looking into using ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination atop' including using ctx.save and restore, but this now makes the entire canvas background white and only shows the background through the image/fillrect.

Before ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination atop' or 'source-in':

[image]

After:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
/*above is drawing the background, I only want to merge the fillRect with the drawImage*/
ctx.save();
ctx.drawImage(o.image, x, y);
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,'+amount+')';
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
ctx.restore();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are after so just guessing.

Draw transparent image

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; // in case not set
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
```

Use "multiply" to darken image

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply"
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(128,128,128)";  // dest pixels will darken by
                                     // (128/255) * dest
ctx.fillRect(0,0,image.width,image.height)
```

Then to restore the alpha

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
```

Then restore default comp state

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```

An example of darkening and image. Image on left is darkened via method above. Right image is the original none darkened image. background colour is the colour under the canvas.

```js
 
 
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// create an image to darken
const image = document.createElement("canvas");
image.width = 150;
const ctx1 = image.getContext("2d");
ctx1.beginPath()
ctx1.fillStyle = "#0F0";
ctx1.strokeStyle = "#FA0";
ctx1.lineWidth = 20;
ctx1.arc(75,75,50,0,Math.PI*2);
ctx1.fill();
ctx1.stroke();

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; // in case not set
ctx.drawImage(image,0,10);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply"
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(128,128,128)";  // dest pixels will darken by
                                     // (128/255) * dest
ctx.fillRect(0,10,image.width,image.height)
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
ctx.drawImage(image,0,10);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; 

ctx.font = "16px arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillText("Darkened image",10,14);
ctx.drawImage(image,150,10);
ctx.fillText("Original image",160,14);
```

```css
canvas { border : 2px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

If you already have pixel content on the canvas you will need to use an offscreen canvas to darken the image and then use that image to draw to the canvas.

```
// create an image to hold darkened copy of image
const dImage - document.createElement("canvas");
dImage.width = image.width;
dImage.height - image.height;
const dctx = dImage.getContext("2d");
dctx.drawImage(image,0,0);

// apply darkening to dctx as shown in answer above.

ctx.drawImage(dImage,0,0);  // draws darkened image on canvas
```

Comment: that still makes the background white. it darkens the image without its transparency but makes the background white. maybe i should put these on a new canvas element layer.

Comment: You have not supplied enough information. The background can not be made white by the above code as `multiply` will make all pixels darker and the `destination-in` will only affect the alpha channel. I will mod answer to make it clearer

Comment: Ok well I did say I'm drawing a background above, as in fillRect you can also see that in my image.

Comment: Now I have put it on a seperate canvas, when I do this operation in a loop for multiple objects, they all disappear except the last object. This operation wipes out all previous draws except the final one. Is there a way to do this operation to multiple objects, each with a different darkness.

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell I have updated the answer, hopefully that will help you.